# sum of consecutive numbers untill given number

Tags: math

I want to find a formula to make this calculation on a programming project but i can't find out the name of this term.
Let's say i have a number `3` . First i have to find all the numbers until this number.. so `{ 1, 2, 3 }`
Now i have to add the numbers

```
((1) + (2) + (3) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 3) + (2 + 3) + (1 +2 +3)) = 24
```

How this term is called and is there a formula for this?
I have tried some different ways in php to accomplised this task but my formula is wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean that you need all positive consecutive integers before the number?

Comment: @synchronizer yes, all consecutive numbers untill given number.

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the sum of all subsets of the set 1, ... n.

Comment: @synchronizer i don't know how this term is called. English is not my mother tongue and i don't know how to search it on google

Comment: @synchronizer yes this is exacly what i was looking for. Thank you very much. cheers

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this, I usually write out the first few examples and see where it takes me, i.e. if I see any patterns.

```
f(2) = 
(1)+(2)
+(1+2)
= 2*(1+2) = 6

f(3) =
(1)+(2)+(3)
+(1+2)+(1+3)+(2+3)
+(1+2+3)
= 4*(1+2+3) = 24

f(4) =
(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)
+(1+2)+(1+3)+(1+4)+(2+3)+(2+4)+(3+4)
+(1+2+3)+(1+2+4)+(1+3+4)+(2+3+4)
+(1+2+3+4)
= 8*(1+2+3+4) = 80
```

So the problem simplifies down to:

```
f(x) = 2^(x-1)*(x+(x-1)+...+2+1)
```

Also, the formula for `(x+(x-1)+...+2+1)` is known, which is `x*(x+1)/2`. Therefore, the formula is:

```
f(x) = 2^(x-1)*x*(x+1)/2
```

However, we can further simplify `2^(x-1)/2` to `2^(x-2)`.

Therefore, the final formula is:

```
f(x) = 2^(x-2)*x*(x+1)
```

Trying a few examples to verify it works:

```
f(2) = 2^(0)*2*3 = 6

f(3) = 2^(1)*3*4 = 24

f(4) = 2^(2)*4*5 = 80
```